# How to add this Custom Object to Package in Package Manager?

Tags: custom-object, package, package-manager

I want to add Commerce Diagnostic Custom Object to the package. It should show up in Custom Objects under the 'Hawkeye' package I'm creating, but it doesn't. How can I add this to the package? [image]
[image][image]

Comment: I assume you have this custom object deployed to your 1GP managed package's packaging org and are using an appropriate admin user with necessary permissions...?

Comment: Oh, I realized the object was already added. It was hard to find among multiple things and I assumed all I've added would have a 'Remove' button, but not all do. Thanks!